# Failed to start Nexus oss on redhat linux server 6.5

Tags: nexus

I have installed nexus 2.8.1-01 on linux server 6.5, but when I try to start it's got the following result. Would someone help me?

> [uszbwp6@ANV-WFM-DLAPP01 nexus-2.8.1-01]$ ./bin/nexus start`
>
> Starting Nexus OSS...
> Failed to start Nexus OSS.

Thanks,
bob

Comment: There should be logs...

Comment: Is there any output in the logs/wrapper.log

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't run Nexus as root, this is not recommended.

I'm guessing that the files in the Nexus installation have incorrect permissions?

Try changing the owner of the Nexus installation files to your user ID (or whatever user ID is supposed to run Nexus).

Comment: What makes you think `uszbwp6` is root?

Comment: After changing the owner of the Nexus installation files. It started working. Thank you all.

Comment: Thx, it worked for me after I changed the owner of the sonatype-work directory too.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. I initially ran nexus as a root user and i saw a warning "not advised to run as root user". So I stopped the nexus service, tried to restart with nexus user but it didn't restart. The only reason is, when I first ran the nexus as `root` user, it created some cache files and log files as a root user.

Our nexus installation is on `/opt` and our nexus db is on `/mnt`

Solution:

`chown -R nexus:nexus /opt/nexus`

`chown -R nexus:nexus /mnt/nexus/`

Afterwards, I restarted nexus and boom, it worked.